# Weird NavBar stretching in ios 11 Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, xcode9

Having a little problem with my NavBar buttons atm. I upgraded to Xcode 9 / ios 11 and suddenly the UIBarButtonItems which used to be little buttons on the side of navbar (like your back or edit buttons in standard ios apps) have begun stretching massively. Here is a photo:

[image: The Problem]

My code is simply:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image2, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(messageScreen))
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift:**

```
let widthConstraint = button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
let heightConstraint = button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
heightConstraint.isActive = true
widthConstraint.isActive = true
```

**Objective C:**

```
[button.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:30].active = YES;
[button.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:30].active = YES;
```

***// add those lines before setting navigation buttons***

Comment: Can you give me the objective-c version for this code?

Comment: sorry ı dont know objective-c.

Comment: @priyadharshini hey, i added objective c version after a year :D

Comment: hahaha @Okan you have been learned Objective-C after two years :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use proper size for your icon. [Human Interface Guidelines
iOS](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/)